# SUP android native app

Tags: android

Is it possible to have user put in connection properties like ip address in the app to connect to Sybase. I need to find out for a test to connect to our DR Site which has a different IP address. (So user uses production system and something happens and need to switch to the DR Site to continue working.)

Thanks
Louis

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about SUP, but it seems the IP address of the server is in the generated code (Activity classes), you cam edit this code to get the IP from somewhere (e.g. the application settings).

If you don't have access to the source code of the application and this is just for a test you can configure your android device to use a proxy ([How to change proxy settings in Android (especially in Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068905/how-to-change-proxy-settings-in-android-especially-in-chrome)) and then make a simple proxy that redirects connections to another host (such as those described in [seriously simple python HTTP proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412581/seriously-simple-python-http-proxy)).