# Proxy server using Django

Tags: python, django, proxy, server

I am trying to create a local proxy server in django, but I am unable to redirect the proxy requests to my view. In my system settings, I have set my django server as the proxy.

I am getting logs as such in my server:

> [27/Dec/2016 22:01:40]"CONNECT www.google.co.in:443 HTTP/1.1" 404 1783

My URL configuration is:

> url(r'^.*$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name=u'homepage',
>   permanent=False))

What am I doing wrong while trying to redirect any browser request to my view?

Comment: You mean you want to redirect to google.com when `/` ?

Comment: When I hit google.com in my browser, the browser is forwarding the request to my proxy server. I want my server to pick up that request, hit google and return the response back to the browser.The problem is I don't know how to configure the urls.py so that a proxy request finds its way to my view.

Comment: django isn't suited for this. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to build a content filtering proxy server so that all requests and responses pass through my django server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are comparing a proxy server with an wsgi based http server, when you run a Django development server ( `python manage.py runserver`), Django runs a wsgi compatible http server, that handles only requests ( URIs ?), not a tcp request content, so you need a http proxy server that copies the request buffer to the application server atleast.There are many available but if you need to implement own, there is already an answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412581/seriously-simple-python-http-proxy)